# Uncaught Error: Script error for "plotly" http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, kaggle

I am learning `plotly` from someone's code, but every time when i try to run a particular code for look at the target column to see how balanced the dataset is,
an error message pop ups and session got disrupted.

**popup error message:**

> Error occurred while loading the notebook: Uncaught Error: Script
> error for "plotly" http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror

**Code that gave me error**

```
fig = px.histogram(
    train_df, 
    x=target_column, 
    color=target_column,
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.G10,
)
fig.update_layout(
    title_text='Target distribution', # title of plot
    xaxis_title_text='Value', # xaxis label
    yaxis_title_text='Count', # yaxis label
    bargap=0.2, # gap between bars of adjacent location coordinates
    paper_bgcolor=primary_bgcolor,
    plot_bgcolor=primary_bgcolor,
)
fig.update_xaxes(
    title='Target class',
    categoryorder='category ascending',
)
fig.show()
```

After visiting documentation i understand it is a browser related error but i do not understand how to prevent it. I am using `chrome` browser, and `kaggle` kernel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue.

There seems to be an issue with the source from which Plotly is loaded. Changing the notebook mode might help.

```
from plotly.offline import plot, iplot, init_notebook_mode
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Taken from here:

https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/138599

Comment: it helped so i am accepting your answer. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common type of error we get when working on Kaggle. We need to maintain the offline version of plotly for interactive charts.

The code will be:

```
from plotly.offline import iplot, init_notebook_mode
import plotly.express as px
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
iplot(fig)
```

You can also refer to my Kaggle notebook on plotly based visualizations from here:
https://www.kaggle.com/vardhansiramdasu/student-performance-analysis